# PHP sqlsrv_fetch_array only loops through half of the results

Tags: php, sql, sqlsrv

When looping through the result set of ( 60 rows ) PHP only loops through a few of the results.  If I do not sort the results it returns four.  If I sort the results by their ID it returns 31 results.  I believe it may have something to do with the size of the data in each row but I cannot be sure.  The view I am selecting from has 50 columns about a quarter of which are HTML code and I believe those have a datatype of varchar(max). I am using the following specs and code.
Microsoft SQL SERVER 2008
PHP 7.2
ODBC 17
PHP Execution time is 900 seconds
PHP Memory limit is 4096MB

```
$connection_info = array();
$connection_info["Database"] = "database";
$connection_info["UID"] = "username";
$connection_info["PWD"] = "password"
$connection = sqlsrv_connect( "server", $connection_info );
result = sqlsrv_query( $connection, "SELECT * FROM server.[database].[dbo].[table]", array(), array( "Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET ) );

while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC ) ) {
    echo $row["id"] . " " . var_dump( sqlsrv_errors() ) . "<br>";
    }
echo var_dump( sqlsrv_errors() );
```

The last check of sqlsrv_errors() returns an error of:

> array(1) { [0]=> array(6) { [0]=> string(5) "01004" ["SQLSTATE"]=>
> string(5) "01004" [1]=> int(0) ["code"]=> int(0) [2]=> string(71)
> "[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]String data, right
> truncation" ["message"]=> string(71) "[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for
> SQL Server]String data, right truncation" } }

Comment: Does while (sqlsrv_fetch($result)) {echo sqlsrv_get_field($result, 0 )."\n";} gives an error?

Comment: No it does not, that iterates through the first value of all 63 results.  However, I attempted to change 0 to 9 ( one of the columns that has a lot of data in it ) and I got resource id # then the id number. sqlsrv_errors() returns null.

Comment: OK, then can you get all row data correctly with sqlsrv_get_field()?

Comment: Unfortunately that is not a possibility.  The function that the code is being used in is supposed to gather data from all tables listed in an array.  Not all tables will have the same amount of results or same amount of columns.

Comment: Did anyone ever find a solution to this?

Comment: Unfortunately no.  We ended up selecting the data we needed from a different database.  Due to not ever finding a solution, the only thing I can recommend would be to either see if the data is housed in more than one database, or try to create a view or SP to select the data.

Comment: Did you try ``$connection_info['CharacterSet'] = 'UTF-8'`` (default is SQLSRV_ENC_CHAR) varchar vs nvarchar and utf-8 vs win1252 encoding issue

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue.

I found the loop would stop seemingly randomly. This is the way I fixed my issue. When the loop reaches a point where the server produces an error (which can be displayed using 'sqlsrv_errors')

```
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC ) ) {  
echo $row["id"] . " " . var_dump( sqlsrv_errors() ) . "<br>"; 
}
```

This is the way I avoided the issue:

```
$params = array();
$options = array("Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET);
$result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query, $params, $options);
for ($i = 0; $i < sqlsrv_num_rows($result); $i++) {
    $obj = sqlsrv_fetch_array($newq, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC, SQLSRV_SCROLL_ABSOLUTE, $i);
    echo $row[0]; 
}
```

I think the issue occurs because it doesn't know how to handle the error it is presented with and for this reason quits the loop.

[This is the documentation that describes the issue](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-fetch-array.php)

Comment: Note that the error row (which returns `false` instead of `null`, both of which terminate the original loop) will still be lost, it just won't stop the loop.