# sqlsrv_fetch_array doesn't return correct rows

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv

I'm trying to `SELECT` some products from a remote MS SQL Server with PHP.

`sqlsrv_num_rows()` returns correct number of records, but `sqlsrv_fetch_array()` in some cases returns 1 or 2 records and in most of cases returns nothing.

This is my code:

```php
ini_set('max_execution_time', 1800);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);

$server = "servername";

$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"dbname", "UID"=>"username", "PWD"=>"password");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $server, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
     echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

$sql = "SELECT items.mtrl, items.code, items.code2 model, items.name name1 from mtrl as items LEFT OUTER JOIN mtrextra as extra on extra.mtrl=items.mtrl WHERE extra.utbl01=342 AND extra.bool01=1 AND items.sodtype=51 ORDER BY items.mtrl";

$params = array();
$options =  array( "Scrollable" => 'static');
$result = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql , $params, $options );

$rowCount = sqlsrv_num_rows($result);

while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
echo $row['code']." | ".$row['name1']."<br/>";
}
echo "<p>".$rowCount."</p>";
echo print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);
```

This is the page url: https://www.eleftherohori.gr/test/sqlsrv.php

Also I have a error message from this script `echo print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);`

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 01004 [SQLSTATE] => 01004 [1](https://www.eleftherohori.gr/test/sqlsrv.php) => 0
> [code] => 0 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]String
> data, right truncation [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL
> Server]String data, right truncation ) )

Can anyone help me with this?
Thank you.

Comment: A similar [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52188725/php-sqlsrv-fetch-array-only-loops-through-half-of-the-results).

Comment: `sqlsrv_fetch_array` is returning `false` because of the error. It returns `null` when out of records. That `while` loop is terminating on the error, but if you kept calling `sqlsrv_fetch_array` when `$row === false` you could get other rows. Just not the error row.

Answer (score 0):

in `sqlsrv_fetch_array()` a fetch type of SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC should not be used when consuming a result set with multiple columns of the same name.  SQLSRV_FETCH_BOTH (the default).
Check this link
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-fetch-array.php

Comment: i tried but same result. do you have any other idea?